# create flexible layout for width & height

Tags: css, dynamic, height, width

hopefully you guys can help me.
i facing some css layout problem.
i want the layout have same effect of auto-expand width and height as table with using div. 
the effect i want is same as below example. layout with the width and height is dynamic and the content inside  all at same horizontal line.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ipsum dolor sit amet</th>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>apple</li>
                <li>orange</li>
                <li>mango</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ipsum</th>
        <td>
           <ul>
                <li>apple</li>
                <li>orange</li>
                <li>mango</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

is it possible to do it with only CSS?
thanks for help if you could give some hints...

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use DIV instead of table, table is not enough flexible and you will face problem when you test your HTML page on different browsers.

Comment: Post solutions - this should be a comment.

Comment: ya~ i know.. so i want used div.

Comment: but the problem is i have no idea how to create the same effect as table. i want my left side content has same width without setting the width. my content inside <th> is dynamic content, same as content height in <td>.